# Why does Powershell silently convert a string array with one item to a string

Tags: powershell, pipe

Consider the following Powershell script, which searches for folders in C:\ with a 'og' in their name:

```
PS C:\> (ls | %{$_.Name} | ?{$_.Contains("og")})
PerfLogs
Program Files
setup.log
```

Now I narrow down the search to get only one item:

```
PS C:\> (ls | %{$_.Name} | ?{$_.Contains("Prog")})
Program Files
```

The strange thing is that the first operation yields an **array**, whereas the second operation (which is IMHO semantically the same operation, so it should yield the same type of result) yields a **string**. This can be seen in the following result:

```
PS C:\> (ls | %{$_.Name} | ?{$_.Contains("og")}).Length
3
PS C:\> (ls | %{$_.Name} | ?{$_.Contains("Prog")}).Length
13
```

This can be very irritating, since apparently there are less folders which match 'og' than those who match 'Prog'.

Evidently, PowerShell implicitly 'unboxes' a single-item array to a single object, and we never get an array of length 1. It seems that every time I want to count the results coming over the pipeline, I have to check if I'm dealing with an array or not.

How can I prevent this from happening? How do you deal with this?

Comment: These from StackOverflow may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827862/what-determines-whether-the-powershell-pipeline-will-unroll-a-collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390782/jagged-powershell-array-is-losing-a-dimension-when-only-one-element-exists If you were not piping to `$_.Contains`, then `%{,,$_.Name}` works...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> Evidently, PowerShell implicitly 'unboxes' a single-item array to a single object,

*And* zero item results to `$null`.

> How can I prevent this from happening?

You can't.

> How do you deal with this?

Use the array constructor (`@(...)`) to force a collection (possibly with zero or one elements) return:

```
$res = @(ls | %{$_.Name} | ?{$_.Contains("Prog")})
```

Comment: Not sure you can "force" it. `@(1) | ConvertTo-Json` still returns `1` instead of `[1]`.

Comment: @Marc: [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/ConvertTo-Json) never returns a collection: it reads the whole input and converts to a single string. If you want input objects individually converted you'll need to process each separately.

Comment: @Richard, I think you misunderstand: I, and many others, basically want the entire object (i.e. collection) serialized (e.g. for external persistance). We are not interested in processing each object in the collection separately. ConvertTo-Json should return a string which, if run through, ConvertFrom-Json returns the original object albeit an empty array/collection.

Comment: @Marc The point of this question is to avoid the treatment of a single element array as that element (which is less of an issue due to subsequent PSH changes: note the question's date). You are talking about a completely different case (forcing a collection to be a single object) hence me misunderstanding.

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @(1)` outputs `[1]`. You need to explicitly wrap arrays into `@(...)`

Comment: In PowerShell 6.0.2 Core in Linux, `ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @(1)` outputs `[1]`, but `@(1) | ConvertTo-Json` outputs `1`. It appears that you must use data as a parameter for `ConvertTo-Json` if you want the expected results.

Comment: `@(,@(1)) | ConvertTo-JSON` is an alternative if you really want to pipe the input in.

Answer (score 15):

Note the difference between these two results:

```
PS C:\> ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @(1)
[
    1
]
PS C:\> @(1)|ConvertTo-Json
1
PS C:\>
```

The point is that the 'unboxing' is being done by the pipe operation. ConvertTo-Json still sees the object as an array if we use InputObject rather than piping.

Comment: We just ran into this - and this was the only answer that helped us.

Comment: You sir are a god in my eyes, kudos to you

Comment: What the hell is going on ‍♂️ `ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @(@(1))` gives `[1]` instead of expected array of arrays 

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to this problem is to explicitly set the variable type to be an array like this:

```
[array]$res = (ls | %{$_.Name} | ?{$_.Contains("og")})
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved in PowerShell v3:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2012/03/19/Counting-objects-in-PowerShell-3.0.aspx

On a side note, you can find if a name contains something using a wildcard:

```
PS> ls *og*
```

Comment: [Shay](http://superuser.com/users/12257/shay-levy), I cannot comment on answers yet, but your statement is not true. PowerShell still boxes elements, but they have, as you noted, given single items a "Count" value. Single item results are still unboxed, though. You can test the above example against PS 3 and see the results.

Comment: The behaviour is still the same in PS 5.

Comment: Yep, def still present

Comment: This behaviour is still the same in PS 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, but I had to declare the results in a new variable, or PowerShell just kept breaking down the array into a single object...most frustrating.

Thank you Microsoft for not considering the use case of JSON...*insert seething sarcasm*

```
$result = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @($body) -compress
```

Comment: Doesn't help when your body object has child properties which are also arrays  ... API's that accept JSON as input do not natively assume a string  as same schema as an array of one object :(

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should use `count` rather then `length`.

```
> (ls | %{$_.Name} | ?{$_.Contains("og")}).count
3
> (ls | %{$_.Name} | ?{$_.Contains("Prog")}).count
1
```

`count` returns

- number of element, for array like objects,
- 1, for scalar objects,
- 0, for `$null`.

Note: `count` does not work for `pscustomobject` in versions older than PowerShell 6.1, which was a bug: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.1